# How can I add one leaflet marker to multiple layergroups?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I´m adding markers to layergroups via:

```
var lGroup1 = new L.FeatureGroup(),
    lGroup2 = new L.FeatureGroup(),
    lGroup3 = new L.FeatureGroup();

new compMarker([50.07045,8.24660]).bindPopup('<p>Something</p>').addTo(lGroup1).on('click', onClick);
new compMarker([50.07045,8.24660]).bindPopup('<p>Something</p>').addTo(lGroup2).on('click', onClick);
new compMarker([50.07045,8.24660]).bindPopup('<p>Something</p>').addTo(lGroup3).on('click', onClick);
```

As you can see, I´m adding one and the same marker (identical content) to three layer-groups. Is there a way to do that without generating three identical markers? I´d like to add one but into multiple layer-groups.

I already tried this with no luck:

```
new compMarker([50.07045,8.24660]).bindPopup('<p>Something</p>').addTo(lGroup1,lGroup2,lGroup3).on('click', onClick);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can do it this way using Leaflet's functions: `L.marker([50.07045,8.24660]).addTo(lGroup1).addTo(lGroup2).addTo(lGroup3)` But it has a side effect that when you activate all groups, and then deactivate just one, the marker disappears :/ You might have to write a function that does visibility checks over all layers and decides whether to show the marker or not

Comment: I´m afraid, this does not work. If I do it this way, my marker does not appear in any Group.

Comment: @chrki Adding to your point, the devs declined this issue in 2012: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/598

Comment: @chrki I am looking for a workaround to solve the side effect you described. Any idea/hint to achieve that easily? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const marker = m;
group1 = L.layerGroup();....

group1.addLayer(marker);
group2.addLayer(marker);
group3.addLayer(marker);

group1.hasLayer(marker) == true;
```

Assign marker to a var, and add that marker to multiple layer groups.Then you can check if they are in said layer group with hasLayer.

Comment: Please provide more than just code as an answer. Instead, an explanation of the code and a breakdown of why it answers the question is most beneficial.